# How do I fit 3 figures vertically in Overleaf Latex?

Tags: latex, overleaf

Good day,
I am trying to fit 3 figures on the same page so that they do not occupy more space than needed. Problem is I can not get it to fit.

Here is my code:

```
\onecolumn
    
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.33\textheight]{sections/images/MaximumSoundEnergy .png}
        \caption{Low-Pass Filtered Signal Algorithm}
        \label{fig:image_label}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.33\textheight]{sections/images/LowPassFilter.png}
        \caption{Low-Pass Filtered Signal Algorithm}
        \label{fig:image_label}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.33\textheight]{sections/images/MaximumSlope.png}
        \caption{Low-Pass Filtered Signal Algorithm}
        \label{fig:image_label}
    \end{figure}

\twocolumn
```

I had to use `\onecolumn`  because the rest of my document is in 2 columns.

[here it is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IRXO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `height=0.33\textheight` sets the height of *the images themselves* to to 1/3 of that of the text height.

This does not take into account the room for the labels and the spacing between figures.

You will have to make `height` smaller until all three images fit.